# Rewrite git history to merge two files

Tags: git

**Problem setup**

I am contributing to a large git repository. At some point a copy of many files was made and then edited *while the original files survived*. Now I would like to include back the modifications of the copied file (named `new_file` below) into the original one (named `original`). The issue is that the initial copy was done with a plain `cp` such that the `new_file` doesn't have `original`'s history.

```
original -----A----x-------x-- D-----
new_file       B------x-x-x---C
```

In the sketch above, `new_file` has been copied (using a plain `cp`, creating commit `B`) from `original` at commit `A`, then edited multiple times. I know how to copy `new_file` (commit `C`) into `original` using `git rm original && git mv new_file original` (commit `D`), but this discards either the line history of `original` or of `new_file`.

In other words, I am in a situation where a file was forked and I would like to merge it back, but the fork wasn't done as a proper git-fork, but instead as a file copy.

Note that the branch in which the modifications of `original` have been made cannot be modified, but the branch in which `new_file` was edited can.

**Solution I am looking for**

I would like to rewrite the git line history of the `original` file such that it contains the merged history from `original` and `new_file`, as if commit `D` was a merge between the branch containing the `original` file and another branch containing the modifications made to `new_file`.

Comment: After my answer, I read through your question again and came up with a different interpretation of it: are you looking to make all-new commits, `B'`, `x'`, `x'`, ..., `C'` in which there is a file named `original` instead of `new_file`, for each such commit?

Comment: I am still digesting your previous answer which contains interesting information, but yes, I would be happy with having `B'`, `x'`, … `C'` where `new_file` has become `original`.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need is `git merge-file`, and to find the correct merge base file yourself.  The result of the merge might be fine, but you might not like one aspect of this result.

#### Long

There really is no file history, in Git.  The history in a Git repository consists of commits.  Every commit has every file in it—or rather, every file that Git knew about, at the time whoever made the commit, made that commit.

With a normal `git merge`, you pick one commit by checking it out:

```
git checkout somebranch
```

which gets you the last commit currently "on" branch `somebranch`, and then you run:

```
git merge otherbranch
```

which picks, as the commit to be merged, the last commit currently "on" branch `otherbranch`.  Git then uses the commits, which *are* the history, to find the best shared commit that's on *both* branches, and uses the files from that commit as the merge base inputs.

> Note that the branch in which the modifications of [the original file] have been made cannot be modified, but the branch in which [the copy] was edited can.

This statement doesn't quite make sense.  A *branch name* in Git simply selects some commit.  The commit it selects is, by definition, the last commit in the chain.  *No* commit can be modified, not even by Git itself.  What `git commit` does is make a *new* commit.

That is, we start with a chain of commits, whose *last* commit is denoted by a branch name:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

Here `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of the last commit, whatever that is.  We have branch `branch` checked out—which is what the attached `(HEAD)` means—and therefore the current *commit* is commit `H`.  Commit `H` leads back to earlier commit `G`, which leads back to `F`, and so on.

None of the files in any of the commits can be changed.  They're all stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, frozen and de-duplicated format.  The de-duplication takes care of the fact that most of the file copies in `H` are mostly identical to most of the file copies in `G`.  Those are all shared (and will be shared in the future with any other file that matches, no matter how you get the matching file into some commit).  But because they *can't* be changed, or even used by a non-Git program, Git copies out those files into your working tree, so that you can see and work on them.

When you make a *new* commit, Git stores the updated files—whole copies again, but again de-duplicated—in the new commit.  The new commit automatically points back to the last commit in the previous chain, and Git writes the new commit's hash ID into the branch name:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

Assuming you mean that you'd like to make a new commit that adds on to some branch, and in this new commit, you want a file named `original` whose *contents* are the result of some three-way merge process, here's how you do that:

1. Locate the current version of the current file.  That's easy as it is in `new_file`.
2. Locate the current content of the other up-to-date version of their file, which is named `original`.  That's easy too, as it is in `original` in the last commit on their branch.
3. (This is the hard-ish part but it looks like you did this already): Locate any version of the file that was identical in both branches.  Your description implies that the file named `new_file` in commit `B` is such a file.  It should match the file in commit `A` that is named `original`:

   ```
    git diff A:original B:new_file
   ```

   should show nothing (replace `A` and `B` with the actual hash IDs).  Either of these two files will therefore suffice.
4. Extract the text of each file to a temporary area (three separate files in your current directory is fine, or you can put them in three separate directories, or whatever you'd like to do).  The current version of `new_file` is easy as you can just use `cp` to get that:

   ```
    cp new_file ours
   ```

   The current version of `original` from branch `otherbranch` is easy to get with `git show`:

   ```
    git show otherbranch:original > theirs
   ```

   The base version of the file requires knowing the hash ID of commit `A` or `B` but is otherwise the same as the `theirs` one:

   ```
    git show B:new_file > base
   ```

   for instance.
5. Run `git merge-file ours base theirs` (assuming you used the names `ours`, `base`, and `theirs` above).  The `git merge-file` command will perform a single low-level merge of these three input files, as if you had run `git merge` and it had chosen `B` (or wherever you got the base file from) as the merge base.

`git merge-file` will place its best-effort result of merging into the file named `ours`, given the above command.  If there are merge conflicts, you will have to solve them manually as usual, or you can use `--ours`, `--theirs`, or `--union` as the equivalent of `-X ours`, `-X theirs`, or something that isn't actually available in `git merge`.  See [the `git merge-file` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file) for caveats about `--union`.

Now that the file is merged, you can simply rename it to whatever name you like—such as `original`—and run `git add` to copy that file into Git's index, compressing and de-duplicating it in the process, making it ready for the next commit.  Git's index now contains the merged version of this file, so a `git commit` will now save this version of the file in the new snapshot (along with every other file that is currently in Git's index—you can use `git ls-files --stage` to view them in gory detail, although that's rarely very useful, or `git status` to compare the index to both the `HEAD` commit and your working tree).

#### Note that this merely adds to the commit history

What you get when you commit is, of course, just a new commit, with a new set of files.  If that new commit has both `original` and `new_file` in it, it has both files.  If you remove `new_file` (with `git rm new_file`) before committing, the new commit will lack `new_file` but have `original`, with the contents you wrote into Git's index with your `git add`.

When you have Git traverse the commit history, you can enable Git's *rename detection* and/or *copy detection*.  If Git decides that `new_file` from the previous commit is sufficiently similar to `original` from the new commit,<sup>1</sup> it may identify the file named `new_file` (in the old commit) as the source for the file named `original` (in the new commit).  But there is no guarantee here and there are additional stumbling blocks: see footnote 1.

In general, Git pairs up old and new files by their *names*.  It's only when one file goes missing in the left-side commit, and a new file with a different name suddenly appears in the right-side commit, that Git will bother with the rename-detector.  Even then, you must have it turned on.  It is on by default in Git versions that are 2.9 or higher, and you can turn it on in earlier ones with `--find-renames` or with the `diff.renames` configuration setting.

If a right-side file is new and you turn on the copy finding code, Git will also consider left-side files as sources for copy operations.  You must use the `--find-copies-harder` option to make it consider *all* left-side files as possible sources, though.

It sounds, though, like the right-side file of each diff-pair isn't going to be new, so this won't help, and `git log --follow` does not turn this on anyway—so `git log --follow original` won't notice a rename, and won't attempt to follow `new_file` as it walks back through the commits, one at a time, to show you commit history, or commit history edited down to only show specific commits that "touched" specific files as compared with their parent commits.

---

*Sufficiently similar* requires, by default, a 50% "similarity index" or better.  Git's computation of similarity is rather obscure: it uses the packfile delta compressor to identify where parts of files match, and where they don't.  It then divides the matching size by the overall size.

(The `git diff` code has a `-B` option to break pairings, but it sounds like it won't help at all for your case.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different answer for a somewhat different question.  Suppose we have:

```
...--A--o--o--...--o   <-- theirbranch
      \
       B--C--D--...--H   <-- ourbranch
```

and, way back in commit `B`, whoever *made* commit `B` chose to copy the file `original` to the file `new_file`, but we now view this as a mistake: not only should commit `B` have kept the name `original`, so should commits `C` through `H` inclusive.

While it's physically impossible to change any existing commit, we—humans, and our directions to Git—*find* commits by using a branch name.  So instead of making a new commit after `H` that fixes the name, but leaves us with unsatisfactory history, what if we could *copy* commit `B` to a new and improved commit `B'`?  We'd have:

```
       B'  <-- improved
      /
...--A--o--o--...--o   <-- theirbranch
      \
       B--C--D--...--H   <-- ourbranch
```

Having copied `B'` (with some changes along the way: specifically, with `new_file`, and its new contents, renamed to `original`) to make the new-and-improved `B'`—a different commit with a different hash ID, but with the same parent `A` as before—we now copy existing commit `C` to a new-and-improved `C'`.  This time, we not only rename `new_file` to `original` but also set the parent for new-and-improved `C'` to be `B'`, so that we have:

```
       B'-C'  <-- improved
      /
...--A--o--o--...--o   <-- theirbranch
      \
       B--C--D--...--H   <-- ourbranch
```

We repeat this for commit `D`, and so on, all the way out to the *last* commit on our branch, so that we have:

```
       B'-C'-D'-...--H'  <-- improved
      /
...--A--o--o--...--o   <-- theirbranch
      \
       B--C--D--...--H   <-- ourbranch
```

Now we pull our sneaky trick: we yank the name `ourbranch` off commit `H` and make it point to commit `H'` instead, so that we have:

```
       B'-C'-D'-...--H'  <-- improved, ourbranch
      /
...--A--o--o--...--o   <-- theirbranch
      \
       B--C--D--...--H   [abandoned]
```

We're now safe to *delete* the name `improved` entirely, and, since we *find* commits by branch names, we won't *find* commit `H` any more, or any of the earlier ones back through `B`:

```
       B'-C'-D'-...--H'  <-- ourbranch
      /
...--A--o--o--...--o   <-- theirbranch
```

It seems as though somehow, we changed every commit that was on `ourbranch`.  We didn't—what we did was change the overall *set of commits* that are on `ourbranch`, rather than making a change within each commit.  The originals are still there and if we pay close attention to the big ugly hash IDs, we can tell that these commits—the `B'`-through-`H'` ones—are actually totally-new commits, but who pays attention to those hash IDs?

That's sort of a rhetorical question, but it has an answer: *Git* pays attention to those hash IDs.  So make sure you have your Git refer to your new commits, not your old ones, by making sure that every *name* that picks out a commit, picks out one of the new ones.  Now that you have done this in *your* repository, you have to get all the other clones *of* your repository—which are other Gits—do the same thing.  That's the truly painful part of rewriting history: there are usually other copies of your repository, and they must play well with you, here.

#### How we go about making the copies

Git has two things built into it for this kind of en-masse copying of a series of commits:

- `git rebase`, which isn't designed for this job; and
- `git filter-branch`, which is, but which is very hard to use.

It has one more tool as well, which is the one that `git rebase` mainly uses: `git cherry-pick` copies a single commit.  If you have to make complex changes, driven by a human sitting at a keyboard, to each copy, using `git cherry-pick` is the way to go.  (For instance, perhaps each commit has to be examined by hand to look for references to `new_file`.)

Assuming that you *don't* have to look at each commit as it is being copied, that leaves `git filter-branch` as the tool for the job.  Because it's so klunky—slow and hard to use—it's actively being replaced now with `git filter-repo`, but even current versions of Git don't actually ship with `git filter-repo` yet.  So I'll illustrate the use of `git filter-branch`.

We usually start by copying the repository:

```
git clone <url>
git checkout ourbranch   # use checkout's "DWIM mode" to create the branch
```

or similar, because a filter-branch gone awry can be quite messy.  (Once you're deeply familiar with Git, it's not too hard to recover from this, but by working on a *copy*, you get to avoid that sinking feeling: if you've wrecked a copy, you just remove it and start over!  The original is still fine.)

Now we run `git filter-branch --er... uhm ... what goes here?`  Now we have a problem, because filter-branch has a dizzying number of filtering options.  Which one to use is up to you.  Each has a different purpose and different capabilities.  The *fast* ones are hard to use; the *slow* ones are easier; `--tree-filter` is one of the slowest, and also one of the easiest.  In this case `--index-filter` might be usable, and that's one of the fastest.  To use `--index-filter`, we'd just have Git rename `new_file` in Git's index to make it named `original` instead.  But if we need to do anything with the *rest* of the tree, that gets really difficult.

I'll illustrate the tree-filter here, because it's conceptually simpler.  The way `--tree-filter` works is this:

- For each commit that is to be copied, Git extracts the entire commit into *a* work area.  The work area it uses is not your standard one!  It's off in some temporary directory.
- Then, Git runs your filter.  Your filter can be anything: a Python program, a shell script, a binary, whatever.  Your filter is run from the temporary directory, and can do anything it likes with all of the files in this directory.
- When your program finishes successfully (returns a zero exit status), Git examines the temporary directory.  Whatever files are here, in whatever form they have, those are the files that go into the copy.  So any changes you make show up in the copy.  The copy gets the original author and committer name and email address and date and so on, and keeps the log message; the only thing that changes here is the new commit's hash ID and snapshot and the parent hash ID as necessary due to any earlier copying.

So if all you need to do is rename the one file, your `--tree-filter` can consist of the single command `mv new_file original`.  This will rename the temporary-directory's copy of `new_file` and exit with a success status (because the file does exist and was successfully renamed).  If you need to do more, you can write a program that scours particular files for references to `new_file` that must change, and changes them.  All the changes you make to any temporary files will go into the new commit.  Note that if your program makes backup files in the temporary directory, or accidentally removes any files, those backup files or removals will also go into the new commit, though!

Now that we have an appropriate `--tree-filter` program or script or whatever, we need to pick the *set of commits* that `filter-branch` will copy, and the *branch name(s)* that `filter-branch` will move after it has finished all the copying.  This part goes after the filters and an optional (but you should always use it) `--`, and in our case, we want to copy *only commits reachable from `ourbranch`* and *only those commits that are after commit `A`*, so we would use:

```
git filter-branch \
   --tree-filter /tmp/fixup.sh \
   -- \
   A..ourbranch
```

I've split this up into four separate lines for posting purposes, and assumed that the tree filter script is complicated and is in `/tmp/fixup.sh` (note that this must be both executable, and an absolute path, since the filter-branch operation is running in some unpredictable temporary directory).  The first line is the invocation of filter-branch itself, the second is our chosen tree-filter, the third is the `--` that we should use, and the last has the hash of commit `A` as a "stop" or negative reference, and the literal name `ourbranch` as a "start" or positive reference.  Filter-branch will therefore:

- copy the commits that `git rev-list A..ourbranch` would list out—in fact, filter-branch *uses* `git rev-list` to get their hash IDs; and
- when it is done, use the positive reference to the name `ourbranch` to know which name to adjust.

This means we can run `git log A..ourbranch` before we start, to make sure that this is in fact the right set of commits to copy.  Since we're doing all this in a *copy* of the repository, it's "safe", in a sense, if we get it wrong, but because filter-branch is so miserably slow, it's annoying to get it wrong.

When filter-branch finishes, it will leave a `refs/original/refs/heads/ourbranch` behind.  If the filtering was successful and we're happy with the updated clone, we should remove the leftover name.

If you have tag names pointing to commits that would be copied, note that those tag names will point to the original commits.  To get the tag names moved you must add a `--tag-name-filter`.

(If you can install `git filter-repo` and use it, it's faster and more convenient, although you generally want to know Python to use it to do anything fancy.)